# Difference in variance of Cys in protein sequences

Tags: proteins, statistics, sequence-analysis, amino-acids

Suppose I have got two sets of proteins (amino acid sequences). In one set, I find that the variance in the percentage concentration of the Cys is way more (65.34) than the variance of Cys in the other group (0.456). Does it mean anything? Does this have any sort of biological implication?

The concentration has been calculated by dividing the total number of Cys found by the size of the protein sequence.

Comment: It may or may not mean anything. Without additional information no inference can be drawn.

Comment: What additional information is needed in this case?

Comment: A lot: mean cysteine density, other structural and biochemical properties of the protein etc. Basically just the variance in cysteine content won't tell you anything.

Comment: This question would be more answerable with an introduction to the biological context, a description of how each dataset was generated (included the sample sizes), and the relative percentages of other amino acids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because it's extremely likely your sets are not a representative sample of the true distribution in proteins.

Your bias might be caused by an effect on the functionality of the protein, but it might as well be a bias in which organisms are sequenced or something caused by the alignment or the way you are searching for your sets.

Comment: If there be is a hint towards functionality of protein, what is that functionality? Any sort of hint is what I want to know

Comment: I'd say this is 99% biased searching / sequence collecting.

Comment: What would be the bias? What is the biological factor that creates this bias?

Comment: "a bias in which organisms are sequenced or something caused by the alignment or the way you are searching for your sets"